# Full page scroll with animations triggered on scroll

Tags: animation, fullpage.js, eventtrigger

I've been trying to accomplish [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/1848668-Gif-for-Codehelp?list=likes&offset=39?list=likes) for like two weeks now. Does anyone here have any idea of how do this? I won't even paste my code because it's the worst ever.

Thanks.

Comment: also sort of like this http://www.google.com/inbox/

Comment: Fixed minor punctuation issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)?

You might be able to get the same scrolling effect by creating your own CSS3 function with the [CSS Easing Animation Tool of Matthew Lein](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/).

Then pass it to the parameter `easingcss3` of fullPage.js.

```
easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.005) 0.5s',
```

Or, if you prefer, you can go for [jQuery easing effects](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) and use `css3:false`. (although it will be smoother with css3)

Regarding the elements dissappearing on scroll, you'll have to do it by yourself by animating them on a callback such as [`onLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction) or by using the classes added to the body as [in this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M).

```
body.fp-viewing-page2-slide1 #section1 .moveOut{
    transform: translate3d(0, -400px, 0);
}
```

Something in [this line](http://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/yNxgJW).

Comment: well, what you did looks ten times better than what i managed in two weeks. Ive actually tried to use your plugin and the scrolling works as expected. Its just the triggering of the animations thats a total mess.. The issue is with the element being in the DOM already but not visible in the viewport and not knowing when to add the animation class. Ive tried with waypoints but it seems overly complicated to just fire one or two animation(s).

Comment: Plus i really appreciate all of your work. Really admire it.